# ReferenceError: confirm is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js

I am running a unit test against a function using mocha . I see this error  **ReferenceError: confirm is not defined**. How to I solve this?

**file.js**

```
function writeTOFile(server, pin) {
  let dContinue = confirm("You are uploading a file . Do you want to continue?");
  if(dContinue) {
   //do something
  } else {
   ....
  }        
}
```

**test.spec.js

```
let file = require("file.js");
const expect = require('chai').expect;

it('test something',function (){
file.writeTOFile("fghsssbn", "5647");
expect(somevalue).to.be(something);
})
```

When I run mocha test.js, I see the above, how to get passed through this error.

Comment: I think you need window.confirm not just confirm

Comment: confirm is define in a browser. In your context ( unit-testing) , it might not be defined since you are running the test through nodejs CLI. You might have to mock that aswell.

Comment: Confirm is a window global function in a browser context but the mocha tests are running on the server.

Comment: Yeah I realised that instantly after posting :D

Comment: @InchHigh `Yeah I realised that instantly after posting` https://rubberduckdebugging.com/

Comment: Can I somehow mock this using mocha?

Comment: @Nico No idea what you're implying haha

Comment: :) I am new mocha unit test, this JS runs on client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the unit test solution in the `node` test environment. You should stub the `confirm` method in the `global` variable.

`file.js`:

```js
function writeTOFile(server, pin) {
  let dContinue = confirm("You are uploading a file . Do you want to continue?");
  if (dContinue) {
    console.log("do something");
  } else {
    console.log("do another thing");
  }
}

module.exports = { writeTOFile };
```

`file.test.js`:

```js
const sinon = require("sinon");
const file = require("./file");

describe("59883330", () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    sinon.restore();
  });
  it("should do something", function() {
    global.confirm = sinon.stub().returns(true);
    sinon.stub(console, "log");
    file.writeTOFile("fghsssbn", "5647");
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(global.confirm, "You are uploading a file . Do you want to continue?");
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(console.log, "do something");
  });

  it("should do another thing", () => {
    global.confirm = sinon.stub().returns(false);
    sinon.stub(console, "log");
    file.writeTOFile("fghsssbn", "5647");
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(global.confirm, "You are uploading a file . Do you want to continue?");
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(console.log, "do another thing");
  });
});
```

Unit test results with 100% coverage:

```sh
 59883330
    ✓ should do something
    ✓ should do another thing


  2 passing (11ms)

--------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File          |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
--------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files     |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 file.js      |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 file.test.js |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
--------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
```

If your test environment is `browser`, the `confirm` method exists in the `window` variable.

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/mocha-chai-sinon-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/59883330